# Custom liquid cooling loop malfunctioning pump

Tags: cpu, cooling, water-cooling

I'm running into some troubles.. I have a custom loop water cooled pc.
It has two reservoirs, with little "fountains" inside..

The left resevoir running the GPU loop, it's fountain is pumping water out.
The second on of the CPU is not pumping water out, however my PC runs fine and CPU temp lays between 50 and 85 C

However i feel both pumps have activity (and trying to pump) but as said one reservoir has water coming out of the fountain inside, the other not. Looks like it's not pumping anything round.

Attached a picure of the CPU temp and a homemade drawing of the reservoir.

What I should note is (even I don't think it matters) the level of the liquid in the second reservoir was below the "fountain". Doesnt seem to matter to me as the intake is at the bottom and the output through the fountain so it could not have run "dry".

Somebody has a clue of what's going on here ?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you switch the two pumps does the behavior switch?  **Yes** I do realize what I am asking.  However, if it's a bad pump, then the behavior will shift to the other loop.  This check will confirm you have a bad pump.

Comment: Well I don't want to risk both videocards hooked up to that loop :(